# How can I get the following code so that it debugs without error?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, switch-statement

This code that I've written is coming up with errors that I don't understand how to fix. Here's what I want it to do:
Create 3 cases in which the user is allowed to choose between case 1 or 2(any other case will result in the default case)

Case1: Take input from the user (in this case, a double input named zmultiplier), take that double, multiply it by each element in array z, and display the resulting array(named result).

Case2: I want the program to go through each array element, and print each array element that is evenly divisible by 2 or 5.

Default: Print "array z is not changed"

Here's what I've written:

```
package jm;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Jm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int [][] z = {{8,15,22,28,36,40},{43,45,48,59,66,70}};  
    int Case;
    double zmultiplier;
    int arrayelement;
    int row=0;
    int column=0;

    System.out.println("Enter case: ");

    Case = input.nextInt(); 
    switch(Case)
    {
     case 1: 
            System.out.println("Enter number to multiply array z by: ");
    zmultiplier = input.nextDouble(); 
    double [][] result = new double [row][column];
    for (;row < z.length; row++ )
    { for (;column < z[row].length; column++ )
     result[row][column] = result[row][column] * zmultiplier;
        System.out.printf( "%d ", result[row][column]);
    }

            break;

        case 2:
           for ( int row = 0; row < array.length; row++);
            {
            for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++);

                if (arrayelement%2 == 0) || (arrayelement%5 == 0);
                System.out.println(arrayelement); 
                     break;

                default: 
                     System.out.println("array z is not changed");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

If anyone can solve this for me and explain in detail(and Layman's terms) what I did wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Well it would help if you'd tell us what errors you're getting. It would also help if you formatted your code more conventionally.

Comment: Why you add semicolon ';' to end of for-loop and if condition as follows: for ( int row = 0; row < array.length; row++);  if (arrayelement%2 == 0) || (arrayelement%5 == 0); Remove them first.

Comment: Sorry about that, this is the first time I've used this, and I'm just beginning to learn Java. For output, I'm getting the following:                                                              run:
Enter case: 
1
Enter number to multiply array z by: 
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at quiz3.Quiz3.main(Quiz3.java:29)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: I'm also getting various errors beginning at case2 and continuing it to the end. If you put it in a compiler, you'll see the errors line by line

Answer (score 4):

For a *start* both of these look wrong:

```
for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++);

if (arrayelement%2 == 0) || (arrayelement%5 == 0);
```

Here you're using a `;` as the entire body of both the `if` statement and the `for` loop. It's equivalent to:

```
for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
}

if (arrayelement%2 == 0) || (arrayelement%5 == 0) {
}
```

I suspect that's not actually what you meant. I strongly suggest that you *always* use braces for loops and `if` statements, even if you only have a single statement within those braces - it helps to keep things clear.